# Python: Print each match just one time with if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement, find-occurrences

Am trying to check the existence of a list of strings in other list, it might exist more that one time, so when I print the result am getting more then 1 occurance in the result and I want it to print each occurance one time:

This is what I have been doing so far:

```
    for i in range (0, len(spec)):
        if spec[i] in my_list:
            print ("R7:You mean:",spec[i])
```

spec is a list of strings that am trying to test if each one of them exists in other list (my_list), strings might be duplicated in my_list ( a string could exist more than one time)

The output am getting :

```
R7:You mean: manège
R7:You mean: mangée
R7:You mean: manège
R7:You mean: mangée
R7:You mean: manège
R7:You mean: mangée
R7:You mean: manège
R7:You mean: mangée
R7:You mean: manège
R7:You mean: mangée
R7:You mean: manège
R7:You mean: mangée
```

The output am expecting:

```
R7:You mean: manège
R7:You mean: mangée
```

Am missing something I don't know what it is !

Comment: what are `L` and `result`?

Comment: Just use `break` in you for loop and it will stop at the first occurrence :)

Comment: When you say "it might exist more that one time", do you mean strings can be duplicated in `spec`, or in `my_list`?

Comment: each time am trying to replace a character with a special character in L (which is  list) to see if it exist in my_list, thought strings can be duplicated in my_list @johnGordon

Comment: @noamgot L is a list with special character, result is the input

Comment: @cajuu' That will prevent 'mangée', it will only print the first one, Thant's not what I need :/

Comment: Right now it looks like `spec` has 2 string items which has 5 duplicates each.

Comment: I edited the question, I hope you can undrestand me now

Comment: I would also put the return of `print(spec)`  and `print(my_list)` unless they are insanely long.

Comment: my_list is a dictionary, so it contains an unfinite number of strings, spec is a list of strings after applying certain modification to an input (The main idea is to apply some modification to string and check if it the generated one are actually words that exists in the dictionary)

Comment: Is that code snippet in another loop?

Comment: Yes, it is snipped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

12 lines of `print` statement indicate that `print` statement is run 12 times given that this is the only `print` statement being fed to stdout, and the statement isn't nested in an additional loop.

Which means `len(spec)` >= 12. I think `spec` has 5 duplicates of 2 unique elements in it.

Try:

```
uniq_spec = set(spec)
for item in uniq_spec:
    if item in my_list:
        print("R7:You mean:", item)
```

see example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    str_list = ["words", "many", "many", "words"]
    word_list = ["mana", "many", "word", "words", "words", "again"]

    for item in set(str_list):
        if item in word_list:
            print(item)

    input()
```

Comment: there are actually more than 12 lines of `print`, and I tried that actually but no luck, what I thinks is that duplications exist in my_list

Comment: @Ran that wouldn't result in the same output. See new example there are duplicates in both of my lists yet the result is different. It may be that your _for loop_ is run more than 6 times.

Comment: It was a problem of loop as you said, I didn't pay attention for it, my bad :/

Answer (score 2):

You can use set comprehension instead of a list comprehension:

```
spec_unique = {result[:i]+s+result[i+1:]for i in range(len(result)) for s in L if s!=result[i]}
for s in spec_unique:
    if s in my_list:
        print ("R7:You mean:", s)
```